# Given this lambda, how can I write it manually with expression trees?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Expression<Func<string[], Poco>> exp = a => new Poco { MyProperty1 = a[0], MyProperty2 = a[1], MyProperty3 = a[2] };
        var lambda = exp.Compile();

        var output = lambda(new[] {"one", "two", "three"});

        Console.WriteLine(output.MyProperty1);
    }
}

class Poco
{
    public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty2 { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty3 { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not interested in the part calling the lambda, thats just for completeness.  I get completely lost trying to navigate expression trees, and this might teach me how to fish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static Expression<Func<string[], Poco>> CreateExpr()
{
    ParameterExpression paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string[]), "a");
    var newExpr = Expression.New(typeof(Poco));

    var memberExprs = Enumerable.Range(0, 3)
        .Select(i =>
        {
            string propertyName = "MyProperty" + (i + 1);
            var property = typeof(Poco).GetProperty(propertyName);
            Expression.Bind(property, Expression.ArrayIndex(paramExpr, Expression.Constant(i)));
        });

    var expr = Expression.MemberInit(newExpr, memberExprs);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<string[], Poco>>(expr, paramExpr);
}
```

Comment: +1, I'm curious, is there any reason you use the `Item` property over `Expression.ArrayIndex`?

Comment: @default.kramer - I wasn't aware of `Expression.ArrayIndex`. I've updated the answer to use it though, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have time right now to translate the complete tree, but one thing you can do is compile your code and then use ildasm (or reflector etc) to look at what the compiler's doing. You can't always do exactly the same in your own code, but it gives you an idea of the kind of expressions you'll want. In particular, in this case you'll want:

- [`Expression.Parameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267996.aspx) to create the parameter (`a`)
- [`Expression.New`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351456.aspx) to create the new instance
- [`Expression.Bind`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355922.aspx) to create a property assignment
- [`Expression.MemberInit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301790.aspx) to assign the properties in the new object
- [`Expression.ArrayIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352913.aspx) for each array access (`a[0]` etc)
- [`Expression.Constant`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301591.aspx) for the array indexes themselves (0, 1, 2)
- [`Expression.Lambda`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.lambda.aspx) to create an `Expression<TDelegate>` for the whole thing

If I get time later on, I'll try to construct a complete working example.